# AJAX Calendar Format & VB.NET

Tags: ajax, dynamic, calendar, controls

I keep bombing out with the following code. I'm getting a 'There is no source code available for the current location' when the debugger hits the CalControl.Format = "MM/DD/YYYY" statement. Please see below:

```
Dim CalControl as AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender

                CalControl.ID = LetterVariables._key & "Calendar"
                CalControl.TargetControlID = LetterVariables._key
                CalControl.Format = "MM/DD/YYYY"
                pnlVars.Controls.Add(CalControl)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, this issue was caused by a space being in the CalControl.ID property. Eliminate spaces, eliminate bugs.

Answer (score 0):

New it up?

```
Dim CalControl as New AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender

                CalControl.ID = LetterVariables._key & "Calendar"
                CalControl.TargetControlID = LetterVariables._key
                CalControl.Format = "MM/DD/YYYY"
                pnlVars.Controls.Add(CalControl)
```